# Responsive LI items according to the container

Tags: css

i am working on a horizontal sliding gallery. I am using Li's for the image container.
The problem is that the Li height is setting according to the content. i want it 100% even if content is empty.
if i use position:absolute the divs stack on top of each other. please help.
thanks.
here is the css code

```
body {
        margin: 0px;
    }

    ul {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        float: left;
    }

    li {
        float: left;
        height: 100%;
        width: 133PX;
        background-color: crimson;
        list-style-type: none;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

And here is the html code

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the issue in your code? You need to show a code with the issue, which I suppose is when an `LI` has no number inside.

Answer (score 0):

Just set a height to your `ul` element

Comment: @MarcAndre *if i use position:absolute the divs stack on top of each other* What `DIVS`?? Can you be more specific?

Comment: The Li i mean stack n top of each other.